# Javascript/Jquery - Implementing a textfield that contains more than one components

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to implement a panel that looks like the lower part of stackoverflow tag panel.
It should add only free text from a textfield - no ajax, autocomplete or selection from pre defined values

It should look something like this:

[image]

How can I implement it in jquery/js/kendo

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try **[jQuery Tag-it](http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/)** which is a simple and configurable tag editing widget with autocomplete support.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to insert a value with spaces?

Comment: I don't get what you means? If you type something then press space, the new tag with that value will be added.

Comment: @rails I don't think it's possible. `Stackoverflow` also not allow you to put space in tag though.

Comment: Thanks. It is possible between "" or as even better in the last example http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/examples.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tokeninput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) which is very easy to use.

Comment: It adds values from a closed list. no?